# How to add select box in event FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

How to add select box in event? I use eventRender, but after render the field is empty and I can't change value.

```
    eventRender: function(info) {
        var content = info.el.children[0];
        var eventProps = info.event.extendedProps;
        if(info.event.allDay){
            content.innerHTML = eventProps.name+'<br>'+eventProps.phone;
        }else{
            let apartment = eventProps.apartment == 0 || eventProps.apartment == null ? '' : eventProps.apartment;
            content.children[1].remove();
            var districtDiv = document.createElement('div');
            districtDiv.style.float = 'right';
            districtDiv.innerHTML = eventProps.district;
            content.insertBefore(districtDiv, content.firstChild);
            var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
            var html = `<div>
                            <div>${eventProps.street}</div>
                            <div>
                                <select class="select">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Type</option>
                                    <option>Type 1</option>
                                    <option>Type 2</option>
                                </select>
                                Ap: ${apartment}
                            </div>
                        </div>`;
            newDiv.innerHTML = html;
            content.appendChild(newDiv);
        }
    },
     eventClick: function(info) {
        if(info.jsEvent.target.className == 'select') return false;
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GRgRvaW . Athough, the dropdown doesn't seem to be clickable, but it is populated at least. TBH if you want to be able to edit parts of the event it's likely to be better to do that via a popup or popover which appears when the user clicks or hovers on the event, rather than inline. You'll soon have problems fitting all this data in if there are more events on the same day, or the user has a smaller screen or something.

Comment: Agreed with Mr ADyson